# Add Search Bar to a UIViewController class

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I wanna add a Search Bar to my exist UIViewController class. I use iOS 8+ and always I debug my app I will have an error message.

I did:

**.h**

```
@interface mainViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
```

**.m**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResultArray count];
    }
    else{
       return [self.fullArray count];
    }
}

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", searchResultArray];
    searchResultArray = [self.fullArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{

    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel.text = [self.fullArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

But the code will give me an warning:

```
searchDisplayController is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 8.0
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Look at the docs for `UISearchDisplayController`. It tells you what to do now.

Comment: I found this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/ but it is not really helpful...

Comment: How is it not helpful? Did you bother to read at least the first paragraph of those docs?

Answer (score 1):

`UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated and it is recommended to use [`UISearchController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISearchController) instead.

Have a look at the [UIKit Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) for examples of how to use `UISearchController` in your application.